# Preferred remote signer protocol to use

Tags: remote-signer

I can use different protocols for remote signer: TCP Socket, Unix socket, http and https. If I have a secure connection between the node and the signer what would be the most reliable option?

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using HTTP or HTTPS as it is a standard protocol so easier to handle, debug and test. Using a TCP socket means you have to understand that protocol and write specific tools for monitoring (assuming you will be monitoring).